# SQL calculate time difference on certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am having the table in the SQL server with data as shown in the below image. So I need to calculate the time difference between the dates having column value is greater or equal to 3 and the next column value 0. So in the below example, "9:51", value is 3 and it became 0 at "9:54". So the total time difference is 3 minutes here. Again next slot is from "9:57" to "10:02", so the time difference is 5 minutes here. The next slot is from "10:03" but as there is no corresponding row with 0 value. so time difference here is 4 minutes (from "10:03" tp "10:06"). So in total time difference is (3+5+4), 12 minutes. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
   DateTime    Value
3/10/2020 9:50  1
3/10/2020 9:51  3
3/10/2020 9:52  1
3/10/2020 9:53  2
3/10/2020 9:54  0
3/10/2020 9:55  0
3/10/2020 9:56  1
3/10/2020 9:57  3
3/10/2020 9:58  2
3/10/2020 9:59  3
3/10/2020 10:00 2
3/10/2020 10:01 2
3/10/2020 10:02 0
3/10/2020 10:03 3
3/10/2020 10:04 1
3/10/2020 10:05 1
3/10/2020 10:06 1
```

Edit 2: I am also having a snowflake database and using the below queries I generated above table.

```
   with aggregatedData as 
  (
       select count ( EVENT_ID) as total , time_slice(to_timestamp_ntz(EVENT_CREATED_AT), 1, 'MINUTE') as minutePeriod
            from events  
            group by minutePeriod

            union

            SELECT
            0 as total,
            DATEADD(MINUTE, SEQ4(), time_slice(to_timestamp_ntz(select min(EVENT_CREATED_AT) from events), 1, 'MINUTE')) AS minutePeriod
            FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT=>20000))
            WHERE minutePeriod <= time_slice(to_timestamp_ntz(select max(EVENT_CREATED_AT) from events), 1, 'MINUTE')
 )
 select minutePeriod
  ,sum(total) over (partition by null order by minutePeriod rows between 9 preceding and current row) totalValue
  from aggregatedData
  order by minutePeriod;
```

I am expecting below output
[image]

Comment: Can you post the test data as text? Thanks.

Comment: And post your best attempt. And your expected results.

Comment: @DaleK I have generated this table using multiple SQL queries and I just got stuck at the final stage of the calculation. Just to avoid confusion, I have not added those details.here

Comment: We don't need all the queries, just enough to demonstrate the problem, called a [MRE]

Comment: How do you get the time difference between "9:51" and "9:54" to be 4 minutes?

Comment: @HansHenrikEriksen Corrected. It should be 3 minutes.

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: I updated the question with an expected output

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
SELECT T1.*, 
    CASE 
        WHEN T1.Value = 3 AND (X3.Value = 0 OR X3.Value IS NULL) 
        THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE,T1.DateTime , ISNULL(X0.[DateTime],  (SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,1, MAX([DateTime])) FROM SampleData) )) END
FROM SampleData T1 
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SampleData T2 WHERE T2.[DateTime] > T1.[DateTime] AND T2.Value = 0 ORDER BY T2.DateTime ASC) X0
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SampleData T2 WHERE T2.[DateTime] < T1.[DateTime] AND T2.Value IN (0, 3) ORDER BY T2.[DateTime] DESC) X3
ORDER BY T1.[DateTime]
```

Result:

```
DateTime                Value       
----------------------- ----------- -----------
2020-03-10 09:50:00.000 1           NULL
2020-03-10 09:51:00.000 3           3
2020-03-10 09:52:00.000 1           NULL
2020-03-10 09:53:00.000 2           NULL
2020-03-10 09:54:00.000 0           NULL
2020-03-10 09:55:00.000 0           NULL
2020-03-10 09:56:00.000 1           NULL
2020-03-10 09:57:00.000 3           5
2020-03-10 09:58:00.000 2           NULL
2020-03-10 09:59:00.000 3           NULL
2020-03-10 10:00:00.000 2           NULL
2020-03-10 10:01:00.000 2           NULL
2020-03-10 10:02:00.000 0           NULL
2020-03-10 10:03:00.000 3           4
2020-03-10 10:04:00.000 1           NULL
2020-03-10 10:05:00.000 1           NULL
2020-03-10 10:06:00.000 1           NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I need to calculate the time difference between the dates having column value is greater or equal to 3 and the next column value 0.

If I understand correctly:

```
select t.*,
       (case when value >= 3
             then datediff(minute,
                           datetime,
                           min(case when value = 0 then datetime end) over (order by datetime desc)
                          )
        end) as diff_minutes
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=daf40bec5262099bd7623b5c3cee37d3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. For some of the cases, it works but if you consider the second slot, which started at "09:57" and ended at "10:02". In the middle at "9:59" value is again 3 so in this case, the calculation is getting wrong.

Comment: @Dany . . . I disagree.  This answers the question that you have asked.  If you have a different question, you should ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear to you..But if you see the explanation, I said the final output should be 12 minutes...and your answer is 11 minutes.